# Constructing a string from getResource("...") gives an output starts with "file:/"?

Tags: java, url

Lets consider `image.png` stored inside one of the project's package named *icons*, I usually get the icons via `getResource()` method :

```
String imgPath = getClass().getResource("/icons/image.png").toString();
//no problem with creating an ImageIcon with this path
Image img = new ImageIcon(imgPath).getImage();
//but the problem occures when trying to open this image through Desktop
//try-catch
Desktop.getDesktop().open(imagePath);
//or
File imgFile = new File(imgPath);
//error, this file does not exist!
```

I noticed that constructing a string from the URL gives the output that starts with `file:/....`, it makes no problem with loading the image, but opening the file not possible until removing `file:/`.

**What's the benifit of `file:/` that added to the string?**

I thought that maybe the path is to a file, but I was wrong, even targeting to the folders gives this output.

Comment: What exactly is the problem for which you incorrectly thought that this is the solution on which you in turn observed unexpected behavior? (because you were going in the wrong direction as to solving *that* problem). It'd be a better idea to ask a question about *that* problem instead so that you will be provided the right solution.

Comment: @BalusC:personally, I'd use `getResourceAsStream()` instead, but I was kinda interested of knowing the unexpected behavior, thanks for the note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a URL path specific to files. 
Kinda how like web URLs have *http://*, *https://* or *ftp://* URL for file keeps that syntax thus *file:/* was born .

For example copy an image like *test.jpg* to your **C** drive.

Than open your browser and type: 
*file:/c:/test.jpg*

hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>and the image should be loaded.

> What's the benefit of file:/ that added to the string?

No real benefits, besides the fact it becomes a valid URL, it can only be used as a URL and not as a valid path to a file, for that you would omit file:/ as you have seen

See [file URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) for more

Answer (score 1):

The method `Class.getResources(String)` returns a `URL`.  This `URL` may be that of a local file, in which case it will begin with the `file:/` protocol.  However, your application or this class may run from a JAR file, and the resource may be contained in a JAR file.  Sun created the `jar:/` protocol for these cases.  Then, the `URL` might be stringified as `jar:file:/myapp.jar!/com/azad/images/image.png`.  So, instead of using file-based methods, use URL-based methods:

```
URL imgURL = getClass().getResource("/icons/image.png");
//no problem with creating an ImageIcon with this URL
Image img = new ImageIcon(imgURL).getImage();
```

`ImageIcon` has a [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon%28java.net.URL%29) that takes a `URL`.  Look at the [JarURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/JarURLConnection.html) class too. You can't depend on `Desktop` to open your URL for you; that class only handles files. If your URL doesn't point at a plain file, you can't remove the `file:/` from the string.

I did edit your post: you used `img` twice.

Comment: +1 for the `jar: file: /...`, wish I had more upvotes and thanks for the editing.

Comment: Jar files are the reason for `getResource` returning a `URL`.  Programming languages have their internal logic.  Well, except for INTERCAL and Malebolge.